# Delete list elements up-to 6 following length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to delete few list items if there more then 6 list, means delete all without first 6 lists items *(keep first 6 list items)*.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class"items">
<li>list 1</li>
<li>list 2</li>
<li>list 3</li>
<li>list 4</li>
<li>list 5</li>
<li>list 6</li> 
<!-- Delete all due lists -->
<li>list 7</li>
<li>list 8</li>
<li>list 9</li>
<li>list 10</li>
</ul>
```

*Have tried:*

```
var DeleteItems = $(".items li").length; //Delete Extra List
if (DeleteItems > 6) {
$('.items li').addClass('popup').not(':first-child').remove(); 
};
```

This Jquery not able to keep first 6 list items, it keep only first child. How to keep first 6 lists and delete due list items ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> delete all without first 6 lists items (keep first 6 list items).

The simplest way is:

```
$( ".items li:gt(5)" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( ".items li" ).filter(function( index ) {
  return index>5;
}).remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eepjhgc3/1/

P.S. You had and error in html, so fix it: `class='items'`

Comment: heh :) You was 7 seconds quicker, I'll delete my answer

Comment: No need for it, seconds are in question... :)

Comment: @nevermind and how to addClass `.popup` to `.items` if  there are more then 6 list items.

Comment: @Aabira, you should add .popup to ul element, right? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eepjhgc3/3/

Answer (score -1):

```
var DeleteItems = $(".items li").length; 
for(var i=5;i<DeleteItems;i++)
    $('.items li:eq('+i+')').remove();
```

Comment: No. DOM Index is shifted down when you remove items inside incremental loop : [**See**](http://jsfiddle.net/b1rv0gg8/). You could use a [***decremental* loop**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ovcazqx/) but still not the best way for doing such things.